# How many strings of n bits have only two occurrences of 01 in them?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For n≥4 consider the strings where there are exactly two occurrences of 01. How many are there?

Okay, so I first tried brute forcing this to see if a pattern might arise, but I couldn't find one and as n got larger I found it harder to list out all the possible strings with exactly two occurrences of 01. The solution I found at the back of my book was also very confusing.

Answer: A string of this type consists of x1 1's followed by x2 0's followed by x3 1'x followed by x4 0's followed by x5 1's followed by x6 0's, where,

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 +x_6 = n$$

What I am confused about is why x1 has to consist of 1's and not 0's. Doesn't this following sequence 010100 count as one possible string where x1 is a 0 and not a 1? Finally, if n = 4 for instance, how would it add up to 4 if the only sequence where exactly two 01 occurs is 0101? I can't understand how 0 + 1 + 0+ 1 = 4

Comment: Presumably, the strings are only of the digits '0' and '1'?

Comment: $x_1$ can be zero...

Comment: What does "x1 consists of 1's refer to? I am having trouble interpreting it since it sounds to me that x1 cnnot be a 0?

Comment: Nobody said "x1 consists of 1's." Where did you get that phrase?

Comment: The answer says "consist of x1 1's", doesn't that mean it can only have 1's? Confused here.

Comment: Except the answer does not have the phrase "$x_1$ consists of 1's." $x_1$ is a number, not a string.

Comment: What does it mean by this type consists of x1 1's? I'm just not following how this answer came about.

Comment: The answer fails to be specific, unfortunately, but in this case, your objection is solved by allowing $x_1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string $010100$, $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=1$, $x_4=1$, $x_5=1$, and $x_6=2$: the leading block of $1$’s is empty. The point is that you must have exactly two instances of $01$, so overall the string has to look like

$$\ldots01\ldots01\ldots\;,\tag{1}$$

where the dots must fill in for strings that do not contain $01$. Such strings must be empty, all $0$’s, all $1$’s, or of the form $11\ldots 100\ldots 0$, i.e., a string of $1$’s followed by a string of $0$’s. We can cover all of these possibilities by saying that we’re talking about strings of the form $1^k0^\ell$, meaning $k$ $1$’s followed by $\ell$ $0$’s, where $k$ and $\ell$ are non-negative integers. In particular, they can be $0$. Thus, we can fill out $(1)$ to read

$$1^{k_1}0^{\ell_1}011^{k_2}0^{\ell_2}011^{k_3}0^{\ell_3}\;;$$

this is a string of $k_1$ $1$’s followed by a string of $\ell_1+1$ $0$’s, a string of $k_2+1$ $1$’s, a string of $\ell_2+1$ $0$’s, a string of $k_3+1$ $1$’s, and a string of $\ell_3$ $0$’s. In terms of your notation, $x_1=k_1$, $x_2=\ell_1+1$, $x_3=k_2+1$, $x_4=\ell_2+1$, $x_5=k_3+1$, and $x_6=\ell_3$. As you can see, we can have any non-negative integer values of $x_1,\ldots,x_6$ such that $x_2,x_3,x_4$, and $x_5$ are strictly positive.

Your problem then reduces to counting the solutions in non-negative integers of

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=n\;,$$

subject to the restriction that $x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\ge 1$. This is a fairly standard [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem.

Comment: How did we arrive at the x's have those values?

Comment: @user3718584: You mean for the string $010100$, at the beginning of my answer?

Comment: Yes, how did you derive the value of for example x1 = 0, from that binary string 010100?

Comment: @user3718584: First I divided into homogeneous blocks: $0\mid 1\mid 0\mid 1\mid 00$. There are five blocks. To match the description in the answer in your book, I need six blocks, and the first should be a block of $1$’s. Okay, it must be an empty block: $x_1=0$. Then I just counted the characters in each of the other $5$ blocks to get $x_2,\ldots,x_6$.

Comment: Last question and sorry for not being able to understand fast enough, but why did the book use 6 blocks? Why should the first be a block of 1s and not 0s>

Comment: @user3718584: To allow for strings like $110011001100$. You can always start with a block of $1$’s, because the transition to $0$’s doesn’t give you a $01$. Then you must have two transitions from $0$’s to $1$’s, which means that you definitely must have a block of $0$’s, a block of $1$’s, another block of $0$’s, and another block of $1$’s. Finally, just as there was no harm in having an initial block of $1$’s, there’s no harm in having a final block of $0$’s: the $10$ transition doesn’t hurt. The leading block of $1$’s and the final block of $0$’s are optional, but they are possible, so ...

Comment: ... we have to allow for them as possibilities when we count strings of the desired type.

Comment: Since this problem translates to counting the solutions in non-negative integers, how was the restriction x_i, 1 <= i < = 6 determined? For example if we wanted three occurrences of 01, then we can't have 6 blocks. How many blocks would be required?

Comment: @user3718584: If you want $n$ occurrences of $01$, you’ll automatically have $n$ blocks of $0$’s and $n$ blocks of $1$’s. In addition, you have an optional leading block of $1$’s and an optional trailing block of $0$’s, for a total of $2n+2$ blocks. The first and last can have any non-negative integral length, and the $2n$ in the middle can have any positive integral length.

Comment: Right, since we are dealing with bits here, 1 bit would be 0 or 1 and if n = 2 we would have 2 bits and 2 0s and 2 1s I assume?

Comment: @user3718584: I don’t understand, I’m afraid; $n=2$ is simply the original version of the problem. For $n=1$ we’d be looking at all strings of the form $1^k0^\ell1^r0^s$ such that $k,s\ge 0$ and $\ell,r\ge 1$. The single $01$ transition is where the last of the $\ell$ $0$’s in the second block runs into the first of the $r$ $1$’s in the third block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and sorry for late reply! Helped me a lot in preparation for an upcoming quiz!

Comment: @user3718584: Glad it helped!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott could you show me an example where n is odd number, for example 5?